# Select a List from another List Using Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

Here are my classes.

```
public class Product{
    public decimal Price {get;set;}
    public string ProductName {get;set;}
}

public class Products{
    public int Count{get;set;}
    public List<Product> ProductList {get;set;}
}

List<Products> products=GetProducts();
```

GetProducts() returns a list of products from a database. Count property returns the number of items in the ProductList. I need to retrieve all products into into a single list of type `List<Product>` by aggregating all products returned by GetProducts() which is of type `List<Products>`

Using standard looping method I accomplished my goal but I am sure there is a shorter and succinct way of doing this by using lambda expressions. Any ideas on how I might be able to do it? I am stumped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.7.2) to flatten a list of lists.

```
public List<Product> SelectManyExample(List<Products> products)
{
    return products.SelectMany(prds => prds.ProductList).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I tried using Select. That is why I couldn't get it to work.